# Create both Async and Sync version of Dapper methods without duplicating the code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, dapper

Let's say I have a simple class which contains DB access methods. DB access goes over Dapper. What is the easiest way of creating async and sync versions of those methods without duplicating code? Let't take as an example there 2 methods: GetUsers() and GetUsersAsync(). In this case both methods would have the same logic. The only difference would be that, one would call sync and other async version of Dapper method, e.g. Query vs QueryAsync.

Just calling GetUsersAsync().Result is a bad idea. Has anyone solved this problem elegantly enough?

Comment: I dont think there is a very elegant way to go about this, you can use an if GetUsersAsync(bool RunSynchronously) and if thats true call the awaited methods with a Wait().

Answer (score 0):

A method in a data access layer (DAL) shouldn't contain much more logic than the actual query. You could define the query string and any parameters as private fields that both method can access, e.g.:

```
private const string ConnectionString = "...";
private const string Query = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Users";

public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        return cn.Query<SerieDailyValueDto>(Query).ToArray();
}

public Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        return await cn.QueryAsync<SerieDailyValueDto>(Query).ToArray();
}
```

If you have any additional logic, you could implement it in a private method that both versions call prior to executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to your problem but with nHibernate.
Check this (part of my file):

These are most important functions that unfortunately must be somehow duplicated.
These functions do the whole repeatable code. Action parameter is what they really need to do (for example: insert) Context is mainly nHibernate session. In nHibernate every operation must be inside a session. GetContextForStatement returns just new session or previously opened valid one.

```
    //sync version
    T GeneralExecuteAction<T>(Func<ISession, T> action)
    {
        lastDbError = DbError.Ok;
        using (var ctx = GetContextForStatement())
        {
            try
            {
                T result = action(ctx.session);
                ctx.CommitTransactionIfExists();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ctx.RollbackTransactionIfExists();
                lastDbError = new DbError(ex);
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }

    //async version 
    async Task<T> GeneralExecuteAction<T>(Func<ISession, Task<T>> action)
    {
        lastDbError = DbError.Ok;

        using (var ctx = GetContextForStatement())
        {
            try
            {
                T result = await action(ctx.session);
                await ctx.CommitTransactionIfExistsAsync();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await ctx.RollbackTransactionIfExistsAsync();
                lastDbError = new DbError(ex);
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can just use above functions in your public methods:
For example, sync version of save:

```
    public DbError Save<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        GeneralExecuteAction((s) =>
        {
            s.Save(obj); //s is nHibernate session
            return true;
        });

        return lastDbError;
    }
```

And async version of save

```
    public async Task<DbError> SaveAsync<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        await GeneralExecuteAction((s) =>
        {
            s.Save(obj);
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        });

        return lastDbError;
    }
```